# ブラウザ側のJavaScriptから静的サイトホスティングのサーバにログを書き込みたい

Tags: javascript, html

レンタルサーバ上に配置されているJavaScriptを実行しているのですが、JavaScript実行により取得した値をサーバ上のログに出力したいと考えています。
レンタルサーバなので制限があり、JavaScriptかHTMLしか利用できないと思っています。

- サーバはFC2ホームページです
- CGIは利用不可です
- アクセスログも閲覧不可です

何か良い方法があれば教えていただきたく宜しくお願いします。

Comment: レンタルサーバーでもPHPやPerlによるCGIが使えるところは多いので、本当に使えないかどうか一度ご確認ください。ブラウザ上のJavaScriptから直接サーバー上に出力するのは難しいので、もしCGIが一切使えないのであれば、JavaScriptからログを取るサービスや任意のデータを保存できるサービスを利用する（＝直接お使いのサーバー上に出力されるわけではない）といった方法が考えられます。

Comment: unaristさん。FC2ホームページでしてCGIは利用不可でした。

Comment: mjyさん。アクセスログも閲覧不可です。jsでURL内の/区切り最終項目であるアカウントIDを取得し、サーバログに出力したいと考えています。

Answer (score 2):

不可能です。
サーバー側に仕組みが用意されていないと、クライアント側（ウェブブラウザ）からサーバーのファイルに書き込んだり、サーバーでプログラムを実行したりは出来ません。

JavaScript や HTML を置いてあるサーバーとは別にサーバーを用意して、JavaScript からその別のサーバーに何がしかのリクエストをする事は可能です。
こうすれば、今公開しているサーバーの引越し作業などはいりません。
しかし、結局の所この別のサーバーを用意するために、今お使いのレンタルサーバより自由度が高いサーバーをレンタルしたり、PaaS のようなサービスを利用したりといった事が必要になる事には変わりません。

---

ログに残したい事の詳細は分かりませんが、もしかしたら [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/intl/ja_ALL/analytics/index.html) などのサービスで取得出来る内容かも知れませんね。